# is this a bug in Google Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Range.copyTo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to set a cell value to `=now()` and then copy/paste just the value back. If I set the cell value using `Sheet.appendRow()` it works, but if I use `Range.setValue()` or `Range.setFormula()` it does not.

This **does** work:

```
// add a new row
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(["=now()"]);

// copy it and paste just the value back into the same cell
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

This **does not** work:

```
// set A1 to now
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue("=now()");

// copy it and paste just the value back into the same cell
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

The second one seems to empty the cell.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` to the 2nd script like below?

#### Modified script:

```
// set A1 to now
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue("=now()");

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added

// copy it and paste just the value back into the same cell
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

#### Note:

- Althought this is my guess, I think that the action of `appendRow()` might be the same with the case that Spreadsheet is used from outside.

#### Reference

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Doh! That was it. Thank you!

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved.